# How to get list of all added coupons in magento?

Tags: magento

Is there any way/method through which you can find list of all added coupons in any .phtml file in Magento ? Basically, I need list of coupons that are added using promotional rules. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay just to clarify that I need a list of all coupons that added using promotional rules. I am asking is there any way to get them through code ?

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Catalog > Rss feeds. Then enable coupons

The feed listing all the coupons and promotion rules will look something like this: `store.com/rss/catalog/salesrule/store_id/1/cid/0/`